# React.js Bootsrap returning null error, when doing 'simple' tasks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So first time using bootstrap with React and I don't know what wrong here.
I am trying to change placeholder on input while on focus, with this code :

```js
let ColorInput=document.getElementById('addRoomRoomColorInput');
console.log(ColorInput)
ColorInput.addEventListener('focus',()=>{
    
})
```

but I get an error code
""TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null""
I Cant even do console log on ColorInput variant.
my whole component :

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Form,Button,Input } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default function Addroom() {

let ColorInput=document.getElementById('addRoomRoomColorInput');
console.log(ColorInput)
ColorInput.addEventListener('focus',()=>{
    
})

    return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div id='addRoomContainer'>
            <h2 id='addRoomH2'>Room properties:</h2>
            <Form.Control id='selectInputAddRoom' placeholder='Room type' as="select">
                <option>Room type</option>
                <option>Bedroom</option>
                <option>Bathroom</option>
                <option>Kitchen</option>
            </Form.Control>
            <Form.Control id='addRoomRoomNameInput' maxlength="10"  type="text" placeholder="Room name" />
            <Form.Text id='mutedTextRoomNameInput' className="text-muted">Maximum 10 charcters.</Form.Text>
            <Form.Control id='addRoomRoomColorInput' type="text" placeholder="Room color" />
            <Form.Text id='mutedTextRoomColorInput' className="text-muted">Red/Blue/Green/black.</Form.Text>
            <Button id='addRoomProceedButton' variant="success">Proceed</Button>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-fog-k79fr) how bootstrap works with React. Basically it is more about React itself rather then bootstrap

You need to add handlers to `Form.Control`. I added `onChange`, `onFocus`, `onBlur` for example. It is simple functions in which you can change whatever you want. In this case if you need to change placeholder text you can use component state with `useState`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Input } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Addroom() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("Room color");

  const handleChange = () => {
    console.log("handleChange");
  };

  const handleFocus = () => {
    console.log("handleFocus");
    setState("Room size");
  };

  const handleBlur = () => {
    console.log("handleBlur");
    setState("Room color");
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div id="addRoomContainer">
        <h2 id="addRoomH2">Room properties:</h2>
        <Form.Control
          id="selectInputAddRoom"
          placeholder="Room type"
          as="select"
        >
          <option>Room type</option>
          <option>Bedroom</option>
          <option>Bathroom</option>
          <option>Kitchen</option>
        </Form.Control>
        <Form.Control
          id="addRoomRoomNameInput"
          maxlength="10"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Room name"
        />
        <Form.Text id="mutedTextRoomNameInput" className="text-muted">
          Maximum 10 charcters.
        </Form.Text>
        <Form.Control
          id="addRoomRoomColorInput"
          type="text"
          placeholder={state}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onFocus={handleFocus}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
        />
        <Form.Text id="mutedTextRoomColorInput" className="text-muted">
          Red/Blue/Green/black.
        </Form.Text>
        <Button id="addRoomProceedButton" variant="success">
          Proceed
        </Button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please accept this answer (check mark) if it is correct